# How to detect v-for complete event in slot-template?

Tags: vue.js

How to know when v-for is complete from the template?

I using a List component (that I cannot change):

```
<div v-for="view of items" :key="view.nr.id">
        <slot
          :item="view.item"
          :index="view.nr.index"
        />
</div>
```

In my component I set:

```
 <list :items="items">
     <template v-slot="{ item, index }">
        blablabla
     </template>
 </list>
```

There is a way to know when the v-for is complete? like trigger a function check if is complete?
I think about do to function:

```
checkIfVForIsComplete(index) {
 if (index === this.items.length ) { console.log('yay complete!!'}
}
```

but how can I call the function in the template? using `{{}}`? for `:` it seems weird to do that.

Any ideas how I solve this issue?

Comment: I think you're going to have to elaborate on why you'd want to do this. It feels like you're asking us to help you fix a half-baked solution rather than giving us the underlying problem to solve.

Comment: Here for example I try to know when the v-for is complete to raise event to tell the user something.
https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller/blob/master/src/components/RecycleScroller.vue

Answer (score 0):

here are the two examples that you can use, hope you can take this forward:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app1',
  data: {
    items: [1, 3, 5, 10]
  },
  methods: {
    checkIfVForIsComplete() {
      console.log('v-for complete - app 1')
    },
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  data: {
    items: [1, 3, 5, 10]
  },
  methods: {
    checkIfVForIsComplete() {
      console.log('v-for complete - app 2')
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app1">
  <div
    v-for="(item, index) of items"
    :key="item" :class="index === items.length - 1 ? checkIfVForIsComplete() : null"
  >
    {{ index }} {{ items.length }}
  </div>
</div>

<div id="app2">
  <div v-for="(item, index) of items">
    {{ index === items.length - 1 ? checkIfVForIsComplete() : null }}
    {{ index }} {{ items.length }}
  </div>
</div>
```